# python/pygame: how would i get my sprite to rotate in the direction it's moving?

Tags: python, pygame

Im fairly new to python. I creating a game similar to asteroids, and so far I've gotten the spaceship to move around with the arrow keys. can someone explain what i would do to make the spaceship rotate in the direction its moving? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To rotate your ship's image you could use pygame.transform.rotate(). Just pass in negative numbers to rotate clockwise and positive to rotate counter-clockwise. As far as the rotating mechanic itself, it can simply be a variable that changes as the player turns. For example: every time the player hits the button to turn right, the rotation variable decreases by 5. Then simply feed that rotation variable into pygame's rotate function.

Edit: As far as figuring out how to manage handling sprite rotation in conjunction with movement, I'd suggest reading the following: [PYGAME making a sprite move in the direction it is facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346874/pygame-making-a-sprite-move-in-the-direction-it-is-facing?rq=1)

Comment: Because velocity indicates the direction of movement, this can be used to determine angular direction.

Comment: thanks for the help! now, if i wanted to control the rotation of the space ship with the left and right keys, and the accel/deccel of the spaceship with the up/down keys, how would i do that? i am focusing on more of how the space ship would accel/deccel in the direction of the way the spaceship is rotated, if you get what i am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your sprites should have velocity attributes. If your velocity is negative, turn one way. If your velocity is positive, turn the other. Because velocity indicates the direction of movement, this can be used to determine angular direction.